# Remove StopWords in JAVA passed by File

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

I have to get some StopWords from a txt file and removing them from a text.
I get the StopWords from the File with this method, saving them in a String array and returning:

```
public String[] loadStopwords(File targetFile, String[] stopWords) throws IOException {

    File fileTo = new File(targetFile.toString());
    BufferedReader br;
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileTo));
            String st;
                while((st=br.readLine()) != null){
                    lines.add(st);
                }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    stopWords = lines.toArray(new String[]{});
    return stopWords;

}
```

Then, I pass the StopWords[] and the text to update inside this:

```
public void removeStopWords(String targetText, String[] stopwords) {
    targetText = targetText.toLowerCase().trim();

    ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<>();
    wordList.addAll(Arrays.asList(targetText.split(" ")));

    List<String> stopWordsList = new ArrayList<>();
    stopWordsList.addAll(Arrays.asList(stopwords));

    wordList.removeAll(stopWordsList);

}
```

But nothing is removed from **wordList**. Why?

Comment: Why not remove words when you are reading from the file?

Comment: you have converted targetText strings to lower case, ensure that stopWords are in lower case as well.

Comment: I tried. It's the same

Comment: @Shail016 they are in lower case

Comment: How and where you are checking wordList? because this method should be working fine as expected. with that I'll suggest please print 'wordList' and 'stopWordList' too.. so that you can be sure that you're getting every thing as expected.

Comment: I found the problem! If i store stopwords from a context of a file, I get something like stopwords = [one two three]. INSTEAD I have to get stopwords = [one, two, three]. How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Try to also save the stopWords in **lowercase**:

```
public  String[] loadStopwords(String targetFile) throws IOException {
    File fileTo = new File(targetFile);
    BufferedReader br;
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileTo));
        String st;
        while((st=br.readLine()) != null){
            //Adding words en lowercase and without start end blanks
            lines.add(st.toLowerCase().trim);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return lines.toArray(new String[]{});
}

public  ArrayList<String> removeStopWords(String targetText, String[] stopwords) {
    //Make the text to LowerCase also
    targetText = targetText.toLowerCase().trim();

    ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<>();
    wordList.addAll(Arrays.asList(targetText.split(" ")));

    List<String> stopWordsList = new ArrayList<>();
    stopWordsList.addAll(Arrays.asList(stopwords));

    wordList.removeAll(stopWordsList);

    return wordList;
}
```

Comment: I found the problem! If i store stopwords from a context of a file, I get something like stopwords = [one two three]. INSTEAD I have to get stopwords = [one, two, three]. How can I do?

Comment: You can use Split to make it easier, i think so: `String[] stopWordsDivided = stopwords[0].split(" ");`

Answer (score 0):

Edoardo

That does work for me. But, there are a few comments:

1. You don't use the stopWords argument in the loadStopWords method.
2. You aren't returning wordList from the removeStopWords method.

Looking at your comments, I suspect the difference is in the stop words text file. I had mine with each stop word on a new line, whereas you most likely have all stop words on a single line, which you are not separating out.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but It doesn't work for me. I pass in the targetText the context of a textArea (with textArea.getText()), and in the stopwords the context of the file read

Comment: I found the problem! If i store stopwords from a context of a file, I get something like stopwords = [one two three]. INSTEAD I have to get stopwords = [one, two, three]. How can I do?

Comment: @EdoardoTavilla - have updated my answer with a possible explanation.